# TitlePage header and footer containing logo

Tags: header-footer, titles

I'm writing a report, and currently doing the title page. Well, I would like to have a header containing three logos and to have text under a logo.

This is the image I want to get for the header :

[image]

This is the image I want to get for the footer:

[image]

This is the code I'm using :

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.8cm,bmargin=1.8cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=25pt,footskip=30pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumitem}%pou les puces
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%/usepackage{t1enc}% un second package
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% un troisième package
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\floatstyle{boxed}

%\title{\Huge \textbf{Rapport de Projet de Fin d’Etudes
%}}

%\author{Amina GHABRI}
\makeatletter
  \begin{titlepage}
  \centering
      {   \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{pic/garde/ensit.png}
              \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{pic/garde/etat.png}\\
                  \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{pic/garde/arab.png}\\
            \large \textsc{Ecole Nationale Supérieure d’Ingénieurs de Tunis}}\\

    \vspace{1cm}


    \vspace{1cm}
      {\large\textbf{   \@date\\
       Rapport de Projet de Fin d’Etudes}}\\
    \vfill
       {\LARGE \textbf{\@title}} \\
    \vspace{2cm}
        {\large \@author} \\
    \vfill


  \end{titlepage}
\makeatother
```

This is the result I'm getting :

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Starting from scratch is tedious for helping users too ;-)

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer , well add the code i'm using ,of corse i'm not getting the expected result

Comment: That is the cause of your post, isn't it? Other users can start from your document

Comment: Put your images using fancyhdr with `\rhead`, `\lhead` and `\chead`  , do not forget to increase length of `\headheight`.   for arabic text in the footer you can use `arabtex` Since your document is not written mostly with Arabic

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This can be obtained with this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.8cm,bmargin=7cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=25pt,footskip=30pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%/usepackage{t1enc}% un second package
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% un troisième package
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arabtex} % for writing arabic 

\floatstyle{boxed}

\novocalize % command arabtex

\setlength{\headheight}{3.2cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

% page header ==================================================

\chead{\begin{minipage}{0.27\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}\\
Ecole Normale Supérieure \\
d'Ingenieur de Tunis
\end{center} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\smallskip}

% page footer ========================================================

\cfoot{\textbf{Année universitaire 2014-2015}\\
\vspace{-3mm}
\hrulefill\\
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
5,Avenue Taha Hessein-Tunisie\\
B.P 56, Bab Menara 1008
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
Tel: 71.496.066 :\RL{al-hAtf}\\
Fax: 71.391.166:\RL{fAks}
\end{minipage}
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.27\textwidth}
\begin{arabtex}
$5$ ^sAr` .th .hsyn, twns .s b $56$ bAb mnArT $1008$
\end{arabtex}
\end{minipage}}

%====================================================================== 
%\author{Amina GHABRI}
%\large \textsc{Ecole Nationale Supérieure d’Ingénieurs de Tunis}}\\

\begin{document}

\hfill  Réf:PFE-2014-??

\begin{center}
\Large\textbf {Rapport de \\Projet 
 de Fin d’Etudes}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

for the length of header you can change it with `\setlength{\headerheight}{length}`